# How can we handle checkbox in JMeter while playback of recorded script

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario where I need to click the checkbox on each iteration.

While recording I was able to capture the value as "N" and while playback I see that the value is not changing to "Y" as it should uncheck the checkbox.

For the first time the script is running but from the second time I observe that the checkbox value is not changing as JMeter is not able to click or capture the checkbox value while playback.

Anyone please help on this scenario.

Steps:

1. Login to a website
2. Search for an account
3. Navigate to a page
4. Click on checkbox field
5. Click save
6. Logout

Please help me with answers on how to handle the checkbox while playback of recorded script in JMeter

Comment: Jmeter is a protocol-based tool, it isn't a browser, so it may not help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect responses and ensure that they contain anticipated values.

In the majority of cases you cannot just replay recorded script without performing [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the dynamic parameters. My expectation is that your script is stuck at the login page and despite JMeter displays requests in "green" as passed they're not really doing what they're supposed to be doing.

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan
2. Inspect the recorded .jmx script and look for the values which seem to be dynamic. The easiest way of detecting the dynamic values is just recording the same scenario twice and comparing resulting .jmx test scripts. All values which are different are a subject to correlation. It means that you need to extract them using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replace recorded hard-coded parameters with [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the Post-Processors.

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)

With regards to the checkbox "handling" I can think of 2 possible options:

1. Ticking the checkbox doesn't generate a HTTP request (you can double check it using your browser developer tools) and it just changes the parameter of the associated [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request when you're submitting the [form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). In this case you need to figure out what parameter should change the value and amend your script accordingly
2. Ticking the checkbox generates a HTTP request. In this case you need to add an extra HTTP Request sampler to mimic the same request as the real browser sends.